# Working with Excel VBA Application.ontime function & recursive function call

Tags: excel, recursion, vba

I am developing an application for sending alerts for the documents in the folder. When the workbook gets opened using task scheduler, it calls one macro -'startapp'. In `startapp()` it checks for new files in folder after each 2 minutes and sends emails/notifications. In the same macro, there is a call to another function which sends reminder for pending files in the folder after every 1 hour. I have set recursive call to `startapp()` so that the application is in continuous processing. There is one bug: at run time the macro sends alerts  for new documents as well as reminders after each 2 minutes. I want the application sending reminder after 1 hour. Please check the below code.

```
Public Sub startapp()

Call checkuser(i)                    
'finds lastrow and user email for incoming files

Call checklist(i)             
'check new in files according to user selected in the list and send emails

rtime = Now + TimeValue("01:00:00")


Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rtime, Procedure:="sendreminder", Schedule:="true"         
 'sendreminder for files in in folder

starttime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")


Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=starttime, Procedure:="startapp", Schedule:="true"


End Sub
```

Comment: When the workbook is opened, call both `startapp` and `sendreminder`.  Then remove the code about scheduling `sendreminder` from your `startapp` subroutine and put it into the `sendreminder` subroutine instead.

Comment: (I assume that the reminders aren't being sent every 2 minutes until after the first hour has elapsed.)

Comment: I scheduled the sendreminder() in OnWorkbookopen() and removed it from startapp(). I kept the other same. After opening workbook, it sends emails for the first time and then nothing gets happen after 1 hr. Do we set recall to this routine?

Comment: You need to put the code about scheduling `sendreminder` (that you removed from `startapp`) into `sendreminder`,  If not, `sendreminder` will run once but never be rescheduled.  `OnTime` isn't saying "run this **every** hour", it is saying "run this **in** one hour" - i.e. it schedules a single execution of the subroutine, so the subroutine needs to repeat that `OnTime` command if you want to run it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you set your code up as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    startapp
    sendreminder
End Sub

Public Sub startapp()
    checkuser i
    'finds lastrow and user email for incoming files

    checklist i
    'check new in files according to user selected in the list and send emails

    starttime = Now + TimeValue("00:02:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=starttime, _
                       Procedure:="startapp", _
                       Schedule:=True    
End Sub

Public Sub sendreminder()
    '...
    ' whatever code you currently have
    '...

    rtime = Now + TimeValue("01:00:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=rtime, _
                       Procedure:="sendreminder", _
                       Schedule:=True    
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly I did the same and it is working best for me. Thank you so much YowE3K.